# Visa requirements in Bangkok for work Telex processing stamp

Tags: thailand, working-visas, bangkok

I am indian citizen i want go in Bangkok Indonesia embassy for my Work Telex stamp process.
I have Telex copy approved by indonesian embassy.
Can I enter in Bangkok on tourist visa as Thailand offering visa on arrival for indians? Or i need any other type of visa?

Comment: If you're saying you are going to Bangkok to work you'll need a work visa. I've really no idea what you mean by _Work Telex stamp process_

Comment: Not for work. I want to enter in Bangkok for visa stamp for my work permit in Indonesia.My visa application for work permit already submitted to Indonesian embassy in Bangkok

Comment: It sounds like you're an Indian national who wants to travel to Bangkok to visit the Indonesian embassy for something to do with a work visa application (to work in Indonesia)? Is that correct?

Comment: @Zach Lipton ..Right